# Probability about oranges

Tags: probability

There are $15$ oranges in each bag.
Each orange has a probability of $10$% to be bad-looking.
Supermarkets only sell the bags that have $12$ or more good-looking oranges.

> What percentage of all the bags will be sold?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried, and where are you having trouble with this?

Comment: I am not sure if I should times them up, like 0.9^15+0.9^14*0.1+0.9^13+0.9^12*0.1^3

Comment: To be sure, you should first identify the distribution of the count for good oranges among a bag of $15$ when given that $10\%$ failure rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute:

$$ 
\ \ \ \ 
{15 \choose 3} \cdot Pr(3 \ \text{bad-look oranges}) 
\cdot Pr(12 \ \text{good-look oranges}) 
\\ + 
{15 \choose 2} \cdot Pr(2 \ \text{bad-look oranges}) 
\cdot Pr(13 \ \text{good-look oranges}) \\ + 
{15 \choose 1} \cdot Pr(1 \ \text{bad-look oranges}) 
\cdot Pr(14 \ \text{good-look oranges}) \\ + 
Pr(15 \ \text{good-look oranges}) \\ = 
{15 \choose 3} \cdot (\dfrac{1}{10})^3 \cdot (\dfrac{9}{10})^{12} + 
{15 \choose 2} \cdot (\dfrac{1}{10})^2 \cdot (\dfrac{9}{10})^{13} + 
{15 \choose 1} \cdot (\dfrac{1}{10})   \cdot (\dfrac{9}{10})^{14} + 
(\dfrac{9}{10})^{15} 
$$

Comment: The result is around 0.2316

Comment: Is the result then 23%?

Comment: @abc... ((9^12)*(10^15))*820 = 0.23159221991

Comment: @abc... Yes, you and I have the same answer.

Comment: Thank you I have solved the problem. Can't believe the percentage is so high.

Comment: @ abc...  It seems they need to repackage 77% of all the bags to sell. The task seems a lot...

Comment: Yeah... that is just imaginary.

Comment: The count for good oranges and the count for bad oranges are not independent, so, no, this is not the answer.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks. that's true.

Comment: @abc... I fixed it though, please see another answer for formula. I think you need to think of the combination of the good- oranges after you selected them from the bags and the combination of bad oranges after you selected them from the bags.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you please explain this step by step?

Comment: @abc...  you need to think of the round where you pick good or bad orange.In one scenario of 15 pick-up,  1st pick-up you pick a good orange, 2nd pick-up you pick bad one, 3rd pick-up you pick good one and so on until 15 pick-up. And there are other scenarios of 15 pick-up such as 1st pick-up you pick bad one, 2nd pick-up you pick good one, 3rd pick-up bad one and so on until 15 pick-up.

Comment: @kimi Tanaka ; The term "Pr" is abreviative of what thing? Probability?

Comment: @Famke Yes.Do you think it is unusual?

Comment: I think most people use $P$ instead of $Pr$.

Comment: @Famike Discussion here they say it's ok to use it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875310/probability-notation-p-versus-pr

Answer (score 4):

Isn't this same as coin tossing? Toss a coin 15 times and what is the probability of getting 12 or more head when the probability of heads is 90%

[image]

Comment: Yes--but how do you figure it out?